# Laravel 5 register middleware from in package service provider

Tags: php, package, laravel-5, service-provider, laravel-middleware

I'm currently developing a package in/for Laravel 5.
My package contains a custom middleware and I would like to add it to the `$routeMiddleware`array of the Kernel class from in my package Service Provider.
But I can't seem to find a way to do this.

I tried to make a custom class that extends the Kernel class and then I can merge the array with my array.
But once out of the constructor it's not possible.

In L4 you had App::middleware, but that function is no longer available in L5.

Can anyone who has solved this problem help me solving this?

Please, tell me if my question is not clear enough, so that I can clarerify it a bit.

Comment: Any solutions for that?

Comment: Not yet, I'm still looking for a solution

Comment: I think I found it. Your provider should extend `RouteServiceProvider`, then it will receive an instance of `$router` which has the `middleware` method. And we can use this method to register middlewares like it happens when you put them into `Kernel`: http://prntscr.com/6yau6n

Comment: It turned out to be even easier than I thought. You can just call `app('router')->middleware('key', 'Value');` in a service provider.

Comment: Did the trick thank you very much!

Comment: @AnatoliyArkhipov How about writing a full answer?

Comment: @Jeemusu I created an answer for you.

Answer (score 31):

Since Laravel 5.4 (tested up to 5.8) you would call the following line from a service provider.

```
$this->app['router']->aliasMiddleware('my-package-middleware', \My\Package\Middleware::class);
```

Or you can use the app() helper as below.

```
app('router')->aliasMiddleware('my-package-middleware', \My\Package\Middleware::class);
```

Comment: Not sure that is exactly the way to go. Since you have to register a middleware first and assign an array of middleware to it

Comment: This still works as of Laravel 8.x

Answer (score 17):

It's about Laravel 5.6

```
/*In your package service provider*/
public function boot()
{
    /** @var Router $router */
    $router = $this->app['router'];
    $router->pushMiddlewareToGroup('web', MyPackage\Middleware\WebOne::class);
}
```

Comment: Adding to a new group causes "Target class [my_middleware] does not exist" while "aliasMiddleware" works fine

Answer (score 13):

In your package service provider you can access the router instance like this:

```
$this->app['router']
```

Next you can register middleware like this:

```
$this->app['router']->middleware('middlewareName', 'your\namespace\MiddlewareClass');
```

you place this code in the register method of your service provider.

Comment: This code no longer works. It used to, but it doesn't any more.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with these two ways:

- Register your middle-ware inside your general middle-ware provider
- Register the middle-ware inside your package Service Provider

lets try first one by `create` your TestMiddleware.php file in your src package folder and place it in somewhere, in my case i placed it inside `Middle-ware` folder and then add it to your composer.json auto-loader like this:

```
"autoload": {

  "psr-4": {
            "Vendor\\Package\\Middleware": "packages/Vendor/Package/src/Middleware"
   }
}
```

And write your general middle-ware:

```
namespace Vendor\Package\Middleware;

class TestMiddleware {

    public function handle( $request, Closure $next ) {
        echo 'hello, world!';
    }

}
```

And then then add the Middle-ware to your main project middle-ware, in Lumen you should add it like this:

```
 $app->middleware([
    Vendor\Package\Middleware\TestMiddleware::class
 ]);
```

---

**Add middle-ware to package service provider**

And the second way, create middle-ware and load it in autoloader like last example and then create a service provider and register your middle-ware inside boot method:

```
public function boot()
{
        $this->app->middleware([
               \Vendor\Package\Middleware\TestMiddleware::class
        ]);
}
```

And finally you should register your service provider inside your main project (Lumen example)

```
  $app->register(Vendor\Package\TestServiceProvider::class);
```

Answer (score 0):

in laravel 9 in package service provider and in register function  will use
app('router')->aliasMiddleware method for ex:

```
app('router')->aliasMiddleware('yourmiddleware',yourclass::class)
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution for **Lumen**:

```
$this->app->middleware($middleware);
```

Answer (score -3):

There are two ways to register your package middlewares.

The first way would be pushing middleware into existing middleware group with the following method:

```
$this->middlewareGroup($group_name, $middleware_list)
```

And the other way would be registering a custom middleware and assigning your middlewares to that group.

```
$this->pushMiddlewareToGroup($group_name, $middleware_list)
```

You can learn more in the links below

**middlewareGroup:**
https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html#method_middlewareGroup

**pushMiddlewareToGroup:** https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html#method_pushMiddlewareToGroup

Comment: You seem to have it the other way around. `middlewareGroup` is for creating a group and `pushMiddlewareToGroup` is for pushing to an existing group.

Comment: @Martin isn't that what I mentioned in my answer already? Please read carefully the entire answer, not just the code lines

Comment: The method in your first line of code is for registering a group of middleware, though it says `pushing middleware into existing middleware group` right above it.